# Bring Back field deleted from InfoPath Form connected to SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, infopath, custom-list

I have researched a few options, but nothing seems to help.  I accidently deleted a field from my InfoPath form (that's created in InfoPath 2010) and published it to SharePoint List.  I was making a simple edit to the existing InfoPath form and deleted a field that deleted all the previous data in the SharePoint List.

How can I restore the deleted field in the InfoPath along with the data to the SharePoint List?  By the way, the SharePoint List is created in 2013 version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have the backups in place. If so, you can restore the list to the point where the coulmn data was deleted.

Comment: How do you check to see if the back-ups are in place?  Are you speaking of versioning?

Comment: That is something you would have to check with your administrators. They should have scheduled backup for the sites and a mechanism to restore.